# Magento 2.4.2: promo code

Tags: magento2

I just took an order from a customer over the phone and could not find any place to enter the promo code.  I re-created the order afterward and indeed the promo code box appeared in the cart.

BUT, here's what I found - If, as happened on the phone, the user skips the promo code, realizes it, and goes back to the cart, there's no possibility of entering the promo code.  The box is gone and there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve it.

Is there any way to remedy this, or is it too deep in Magento code?

Comment: Can you brief out the steps in more detail which you followed?

Comment: There are other ways to keep promo code show to the users after skip promo code options. I would like to review the existing promo code features over your website. You may reach out me on skype : bliss.ram786 so I will guide you best way to meet your requirement.